# SQL SELECT ordered by reference in another table

Tags: sql

I have a SQL database containing tables 'Users', 'Pickles', and 'Likes'.

Table 'Likes' is structured like: id, userID, pickleID

When a user likes a pickle a row is added to 'Likes' appropriately.

In a situation like this I want to pull from the database the top 10 most liked pickles. Is there any easy way of doing this?

Comment: Did you try anything ? and which `DBMS` you are using ?

Comment: Join, order by etc FETCH FIRST 10 (ANSI SQL).

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: MySQL, I'm rather new to this so I'm not sure if that's ANSI or not

Comment: Most dmbs are close to ANSI SQL, but top/fetch limit/etc is one of the areas that too often aren't ANSI compatible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for a join on an aggregate query from the `likes` table:

In ANSI SQL:

```
SELECT   p.*
FROM     pickles p
JOIN     (SELECT   pickleID, COUNT(*) AS cnt
          FROM     likes
          GROUP BY pickleID) l ON p.pickleID = l.pickleID
ORDER BY cnt DESC
FETCH    FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY
```

Note that some RDBMSs have proprietary syntax roughly equivalent to  the `fetch` clause, and may not support the ANSI syntax, especially in earlier versions.

MySQL:

```
SELECT   p.*
FROM     pickles p
JOIN     (SELECT   pickleID, COUNT(*) AS cnt
          FROM     likes
          GROUP BY pickleID) l ON p.pickleID = l.pickleID
ORDER BY cnt DESC
LIMIT    10
```

Microsoft SQL Server:

```
SELECT   TOP 10 p.*
FROM     pickles p
JOIN     (SELECT   pickleID, COUNT(*) AS cnt
          FROM     likes
          GROUP BY pickleID) l ON p.pickleID = l.pickleID
ORDER BY cnt DESC
```

Oracle before 12c:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   (SELECT   p.*
        FROM     pickles p
        JOIN     (SELECT   pickleID, COUNT(*) AS cnt
                  FROM     likes
                  GROUP BY pickleID) l ON p.pickleID = l.pickleID
        ORDER BY cnt DESC) 
WHERE  rownum <= 10
```

EDIT:
To answer the question in the comment, if there aren't at least 10 pickles with votes, the aforementioned query(s) will return only the pickles voted on. In order to include additional pickles without votes you could replace the `join` with a `left join`. This will allow pickles with no votes to show as though they have a `null` count of votes. You could then use `coalesce` to treat these `null`s as `0`s and then apply the same ordering. Here's an example with the ANSI-SQL query. The others could be modified in a similar fashion:

```
SELECT    p.*, COALESCE (cnt, 0) AS votes
FROM      pickles p
LEFT JOIN (SELECT   pickleID, COUNT(*) AS cnt
           FROM     likes
           GROUP BY pickleID) l ON p.pickleID = l.pickleID
ORDER BY  votes DESC
FETCH     FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: That's what I call an answer!

Comment: What you have done here appears to be magic good sir. I will spend some time analyzing your examples

Comment: Okay... I'm not going to lie I cannot get any of your MySQL code to work and it's absolutely confusing to me : (

Comment: @Parad0x13 What exactly was the problem? Can you share your error?

Comment: Aren't GROUP BY missing in the sub-query?

Comment: @jarlh yes! wow, that was a bad case of [inattentional blindness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inattentional_blindness), repeated times four. Thanks for noticing (edited and fixed).

Comment: @Parad0x13 - the missing `gorup by` clause should do the trick - can you try now please?

Comment: YEP! That worked! With the group by added it does exactly what I need it to do!

Comment: Follow up question! The above SQL code pulls the top 10 most liked pickles, but what if I wanted to always show at least 10 pickles to my users even though say only 3 pickles have been voted on? That means 7 pickles do not have any votes and will not be pulled in the above query. Is there a way to pull whatever pickles are most liked, and if there aren't enough then pull the rest (for all intents and purposes randomly) from the pickle table?

Comment: @Parad0x13 see my edited answer - that should do the trick iiuc.

Answer (score 1):

in SQL-SERVER

```
select * from Pickles
where id in 
( 
    select top 10 pickleID 
    from Likes 
    group by pickleID
    order by COUNT(*) desc
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
SELECT TOP 10 
pickleID,
COUNT(pickleID) AS NumberOfLikes
FROM Likes 
GROUP BY pickleID
ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

Comment: SQL Server? (No dbms specified, i.e. assume ANSI SQL.)

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using MS SQL

try group by with order by sql query and pick top 10 records.

```
Select top 10 PicklelId, Count(*) total from Likes group by PicklelID order by total desc
```

Comment: SQL Server? (No dbms specified, i.e. assume ANSI SQL.)

Answer (score 0):

This is how to get most liked pickles (top 10):

```
select top 10
   P.PickleID,
   P.PickleName,
   count(L.id) as TotalLikes
from
   Pickles P
   left outer join Likes L on L.PickleID = P.PickleID
group by
   P.PickleID,
   P.PickleName
order by
   sum(L.id) desc
```

Comment: SQL Server? (No dbms specified, i.e. assume ANSI SQL.)